elementor loop item taxonomy categories display main category
I created a widget that works on the homepage with Elementor, some of my articles have multiple categories. But in this display, although there are multiple categories in the articles, I want to show a single category on the homepage.
I tried with css but it didn't work

Did you wrote your own elementor widget or use existing one? In the first case - you can share source code and someone will be able to help. Otherwise contact with Elementor plugin authors for the guidance.
